# is ther anyway to use the table postfix name at runtime in ef core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first

i have tables that store data for every month like this:

```
dbo.Data201809
dbo.Data201810
dbo.Data201811
dbo.Data201812
dbo.Data201901
```

All theses table's columns are same and the only difference between them is the name of table.

I use entity framework core code-fist to develop an application which should read and update some data from these data.

my questions is how to get and set data from these tables by using the date attribute (like 201812 for data201812) and map the table to some generic data model.

Comment: Why are you using different tables for each month? This sounds like a bad idea. It would be a lot cleaner and simpler to add a date column to your data and store all the data in a single table.

Comment: First, SQL Server has partitioning, which is free for all editions since 2016 SP1. You don't need such tables. Second, EF is an *ORM*, not a replacement for SQL. It *shouldn't* know anything about how a table is physically stored or partitioned. It doesn't need to either. Just create a view that combines all tables with UNION ALL

Comment: The best option would be to use partitioning. Even without it (eg if you target older SQL Server versions where partitioning was an Enterprise feature), a view that combines all tables will be updatable if the `Date` column in each table has a constraint that only allows entries that belong to the table. This way, SQL Server can find which table should be modified due to an UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE

Comment: These tables are created by another app that can not be changed at this time. It's not possible to use the view, as there are occasions for update operations.

Comment: @ali the view will be updatable if the requirements are meant. There are no date attributes in those tables, just strings what may or may not mean something to one person or another. Read about [Partitioned views](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/09/partitioned-views-guide/) and [Updatable views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#updatable-views). Do the tables have a `Date` or similar column?

Comment: I understand your solution, since there is no simple way to build a view directly in code, I have to write a job to periodically add new tables to this Partitioned View, and this one is annoying. If there is a solution that can allow an extension to be added to the table name at run-time, I think the code would be much cleaner.

Comment: this database schema (at least with frequent updates) is not a situation where you'll want to use an ORM.